# Django image placement

Tags: html, django

this is how I want to display the pictures
[image]

this is how it is displayed
[image]

---

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: white; border-color: white;">
    <img class="mx-auto thumbnail" src=" {% static 'mike/Anon.png'  %} " width = 25 >
    <p > Hi how are you </p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color: white; border-color: white;">

     <img class="mx-auto thumbnail" src=" {% static 'mike/Anon.png'  %} " width = 25   class="right">
     <p class="float-right">Hey! I'm fine. Thanks for asking!</p>
</div>
```

It works in normal HTML but not with Django. Please Help.

Comment: maybe your css is not getting loaded. Check browser console to see if css is working. Or put your styles inside the html for testing

Comment: Django doesn't add anything extra on top of "normal html" since its involvement takes place during rendering the html code. You need to make an [mcve].

Comment: class on second img tag should be `float-right`, not just `right`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#aligning-images

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your template:

```
{% for a in image_table %}
    {% if  a.image %}
         <td><img src="{% static 'app_image/'|add:a.image %}" style="width:50%;cursor:pointer" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity"></td>
    {% else %}
        <td>No image</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}



<div id="modal01" class="w3-modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
  <span class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-text-white w3-xxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
    <img id="img01" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

**In your App (exempale name:app_image ) repertory create folder: static/app_image**

And add this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
```